# Set Cookie for Picasso

Tags: android, cookies, picasso, okhttp

im trying to set Cookie for picasso connections . i found this for OkHttp:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
client.setCookieHandler(cookieManager);
```

the problem is i dont know where to set this for Picasso . All ideas accepted ! thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to use [OkHttpDownloader](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/OkHttpDownloader.html) to tie the two together:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
client.setCookieHandler(cookieManager);

// Create the downloader for Picasso to use
OkHttpDownloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(client);
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(downloader).build();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i will try this and tell about the result .

Comment: The problem with this answer is that apparently using a specific OkHttpClient instance will disable the default caching. :( https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/eb2e9730fb7dbe25b4ab9d4ba5d2050c70c27024/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/OkHttpDownloader.java#L84  And going the other way (i.e. making a default OkHttpDownloader() and then trying to adjust the cookieHandler on the OkHttpClient inside that) doesn't work because getClient() is protected.  Boo.

Comment: Just a note for anyone else doing this and wanting caching - I ended up subclassing OkHttpDownloader in order to expose a public `getMyClient()` method. Doing that lets me at the default client and I can inject the CookieManager to get both cookies and caching.

Answer (score 5):

Overriding the openConnection-Method from UrlConnectionDownloader worked for me.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import com.squareup.picasso.UrlConnectionDownloader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public  class CookieImageDownloader extends UrlConnectionDownloader{

    public CookieImageDownloader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(Uri path) throws IOException{
        HttpURLConnection conn = super.openConnection(path);

        String cookieName = /*your cookie-name */;
        String cookieValue = /*your cookie-value */;
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookieName + "=" + cookieValue );

        return conn;
    }
}
```

To apply it to Picasso:

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(new CookieImageDownloader(context)).build();
```

And take care not to use `picasso.with()` afterwards because it will initialize the builder again removing our custom downloader `CookieImageDownloader`, but instead, use `picasso.load()` directly.