# Picasso working incorrectly after overriding OkHttpDownloader.load()

Tags: android, picasso

I have the following requirements for image download:

- ignoring SSL errors (yes I am aware of the risks)
- using a session cookie

I tried to adapt **Picasso 2.4.0** to do that, below is my approach:

```
   public static Picasso getPicasso(Context context) {
    /* an OkHttpClient that ignores SSL errors */
    final OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

    return new Picasso.Builder(context)
            .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(client) {
                @Override
                public Response load(Uri uri, boolean localCacheOnly) throws IOException {

                    final String RESPONSE_SOURCE_ANDROID = "X-Android-Response-Source";
                    final String RESPONSE_SOURCE_OKHTTP = "OkHttp-Response-Source";

                    HttpURLConnection connection = openConnection(uri);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", getCookieHandler().
                            getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).toString());
                    connection.setUseCaches(true);
                    if (localCacheOnly)
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached,max-age=" + Integer.MAX_VALUE);

                    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

                    if (responseCode == 401)
                        relogin();
                    else if (responseCode >= 300) {
                        connection.disconnect();
                        throw new ResponseException(responseCode + " " + connection.getResponseMessage());
                    }
                    String responseSource = connection.getHeaderField(RESPONSE_SOURCE_OKHTTP);
                    if (responseSource == null)
                        responseSource = connection.getHeaderField(RESPONSE_SOURCE_ANDROID);

                    long contentLength = connection.getHeaderFieldInt("Content-Length", -1);
                    boolean fromCache = parseResponseSourceHeader(responseSource);

                    return new Response(connection.getInputStream(), fromCache, contentLength);
                }

            }).build();
}
```

The only thing that I changed from the original source is adding a `Cookie` for the `HttpURLConnection`. I also copied (unchanged) the `parseResponseSourceHeader()` method since it has private access.

*Note that the approach given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346885/set-cookie-for-picasso) does NOT work (response code 401).*

The image loading basically works, but there are major issues:

- caching doesn't work (`fromCache` is always `false` and `Picasso` always reloads an image which has already been downloaded)
- there's no "Content-Length" header, so `contentLength` is always -1
- though the cache doesn't work, the RAM usage increases when loading next image (into exactly the same or any other `ImageView`), it seems the `Bitmap` object stays somewhere in the memory
- when used inside the `BaseAdapter` of a `GridView`, it seems that `Picasso` tries to load all (or at least as many as the number of times `getView()` was called) images at the same time. Those images appear, then the app freezes and closes with the following (OOM?) log:

`A/Looper﹕ Could not create wake pipe.  errno=24`

or

```
 A/Looper﹕ Could not create epoll instance.  errno=24
```

The described issues occur no matter if I use a custom `Target` of just an `ImageView`.

It seems I have broken some of Picasso mechanisms by overriding the `load()` method of the `OkHttpDownloader`, but I'm not getting what's wrong since I did minimal changes. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has a similar problem: it was a really lame mistake of mine. I was creating multiple `Picasso` instances which is complete nonsense. After ensuring the singleton pattern with a helper class that returns a single `Picasso` instance everything works as intended.