# Accessing web content using a session cookie

Tags: android, cookies, xamarin, webclient, picasso

I want to download a picture from a website, however the site requires a user session cookie to be given so it can open the URL with the picture. I tried using `WebClient()` and send the cookie, but the URL still doesn't open.

Edit: If I do `client.DownloadData(url)` it downloads the picture into bytes, so it accesses it properly. But if I use `Picasso` to download the picture, it doesn't work.
The Application Output is this:

```
    [Mono] Assembly Ref addref App[0xb4710760] -> Picasso[0xb4710ca0]: 2
[Settings] Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
[System.err] remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/data/***********/cache/picasso-cache/journal.tmp
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Thread-5078-732856181: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Thread-5078-732856181: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
[System.out] KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
[System.out] KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
[System.out] KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[skia] --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

Code:

```
public void DownloadImage(string url, Context context, ImageView imageView) {
        ISharedPreferences pref = context.GetSharedPreferences("UserSession", FileCreationMode.Private);
        string cookie = pref.GetString("PHPSESSID", string.Empty);

        using (var client = new WebClient()) {
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "PHPSESSID=" + cookie);
            Picasso.With(context).Load(url).Into(imageView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure the session is the only piece of data required?  And are you passing a valid session id?  What response code do you get from the server?

Comment: @Jason I edited the question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346885/set-cookie-for-picasso

Comment: @Jason Can I do this with `WebClient()` or should I download the library?

Comment: I doubt Picasso knows how to use WebClient.