# How to use okhttp to put a validate code to imageView?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, inputstream, okhttp

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                   .url(url)
                   .addHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+sessionId)
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

I use okhttp3 to build a request with cookie and session, and the response.body() is validate code. The inputStream is not empty, but bitmap is null. I have tried the way below, but the bitmap is also null.

```
private Bitmap convertBitmap(final Response response) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    byte[] bmp_buffer;
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    outStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
    bmp_buffer = outStream.toByteArray();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bmp_buffer, 0, bmp_buffer.length);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the byteArray in the response is of an image?

Comment: Yes. I have used Glide to try the url, and it can be shown in imageView

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use **[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)** for downloading image directly in your ImageView.

Example from home page of **Picasso** library:

```
String imgUrl = "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png";
Picasso.with(context).load(imgUrl).into(imageView);
```

Also, you can put placeholder, while image downloading:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imgUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageView);
```

Put error image, if downloading failed:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imgUrl).error(R.drawable.error_image).into(imageView);
```

Full code with cookies:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor {  

    @Override  
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {  
        Request.Builder request = chain.request().newBuilder();  
        request.addHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+sessionId);  
        return chain.proceed(request.build());  
    }  
});  

CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
client.setCookieHandler(cookieManager);

// Create the downloader for Picasso to use
OkHttpDownloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(client);
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(downloader).build();

picasso.load(imgUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.error_image).into(imageView);
```

Comment: If i want to use cookie, how should I set it ?

Comment: Of course it possibly. Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25346917/3926506)

Comment: hi, I have tried to add cookie to Picasso, but I still can't get the image, why?  client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
 public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
       Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                      .addHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=abc3St68rRb0V7U5UqLLv; cookie_test=1").build();
      return chain.proceed(request);}}).build();
      Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(MainActivity.this).downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client)).build();
       picasso.load(url).into(imageView);

Comment: Have you any stacktrace?

Comment: `IOException` usually about connection problems. Can you check it?

Comment: I put all those codes into a try-catch, and there isn't any IOException

Comment: I edit answer according to [this article](http://blog.csdn.net/guowang_wei/article/details/50536987). Try it